# How to separate a DataTable by a column and store it for later use

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

DataTable (already sorted by `Ee`):

```
Title           EventDate                   EndDate 
Testing 1       3/23/2016 11:00:00 AM       3/23/2016 12:00:00 PM
Testing 2       3/23/2016 5:00:00 PM        3/23/2016 6:00:00 PM
Testing 9       3/24/2016 4:00:00 PM        3/24/2016 5:00:00 PM
Testing 5       3/29/2016 11:00:00 AM       3/29/2016 12:00:00 PM
Testing 6       3/29/2016 11:00:00 AM       3/29/2016 12:00:00 PM
Testing 4       3/29/2016 1:00:00 PM        3/29/2016 2:00:00 PM
```

ASP.net Label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lDates" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

How can I code it so the datatable is displayed in the label like this (It might not be like this, but someway I can separate them by dates and display in different places):

```
3/23:   Testing 1
        Testing 2

3/24:   Testing 9

3/29:   Testing 5
        Testing 6
        Testing 4
```

Comment: A GridView? Repeater?

Comment: I can use a repeater but how do I separate the DataTable.

Comment: well, try create one more `DataTable` using `distinct`, loop trough that table and collect values from first one ... little messy but it could done the job

Comment: First get all distinct dates, loop through them and make a Select on your DataTable, thus you can separate your DataRows and build your html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do that by looping trough `DataTable`, get current `EventDate` and check it with previous on.

This is `vb.net` code :

```
    'get first date from table in format day.month - adapt to Your date format    
    Dim pDT As String = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(0)("EventDate"))
    Dim res As String = "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;'>" + pDT + "</td><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;padding-left:10px;'>" + dt.Rows(0)("Title") + "<br>"
For x = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
   'get EventDate from current row
   Dim nD As String = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(x)("EventDate"))
   If nD <> pDT Then
      res += "<td></tr>"
      pDT = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(x)("EventDate"))
      res += "<tr><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;'>" + pDT + "</td><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;padding-left:10px;'>" + dt.Rows(x)("Title") + "<br>"
   Else
      res += dt.Rows(x)("Title") + "<br>"
   End If
Next
res += "</td></tr></table>"
lDates.Text = res
```

Since I don't use `c#`, below code is converted by online converter (I hope so it's correct conversion :( ):

```
string pDT = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[0]["EventDate"]);
                string res = "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;'>" + pDT + "</td><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;padding-left:10px;'>" + dt.Rows[0]["Title"] + "<br>";
                for (int x = 1; x <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    string nD = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[x]["EventDate"]);
                    if (nD != pDT)
                    {
                        res += "<td></tr>";
                        pDT = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[(x]["EventDate"]);
                        res += "<tr><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;'>" + pDT + "</td><td style='text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;padding-left:10px;'>" + dt.Rows[x]["Title"] + "<br>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res += dt.Rows[x]["Title"] + "<br>";
                    }
                }
                res += "</td></tr></table>";
                lDates.Text = res;
```

It's little dirty code.

**Update (populate `Repeater`) :**

Then You have to create new, empty, `DataTable` and use, almost, same code, but, instead putting values into `string` put them, separately, in new `DataTable` (with 2 columns, one for date and another for Titles) :

codebehind (vb.net) :

```
Dim newDT As New DataTable
            newDT.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
            newDT.Columns.Add("Titles", GetType(String))
            Dim pDT = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(0)("EventDate"))
            Dim titles As String = dt.Rows(0)("Title") + ","
            For x = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim nD = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(x)("EventDate"))
                If pDT <> nD Then
                    titles = Mid(titles, 1, Len(titles) - 1)
                    newDT.Rows.Add({pDT, String.Join("<br>", titles.Split(",").ToArray)})
                    pDT = String.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows(x)("EventDate"))
                    titles = dt.Rows(x)("Title") + ","
                Else
                    titles += dt.Rows(x)("Title") + ","
                End If
            Next
            titles = Mid(titles, 1, Len(titles) - 1)
            newDT.Rows.Add({pDT, String.Join("<br>", titles.Split(",").ToArray)})
            rptDate.DataSource = newDT
            rptDate.DataBind()
```

codebehind (`c#`) (p.s. I'm not sure it's correct conversion. sorry, again, I'm very very weak with `c#` :( ):

```
DataTable newDT = new DataTable();
newDT.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
newDT.Columns.Add("Titles", typeof(string));
string pDT = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[0]["EventDate"]);
string titles = dt.Rows[0]("Title") + ",";
for (x = 1; x <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; x++) {
    string nD = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[0]["EventDate"]);
    if (pDT != nD) {
        titles = Strings.Mid(titles, 1, Strings.Len(titles) - 1);
        newDT.Rows.Add({
            pDT,
            string.Join("<br>", titles.Split(",").ToArray)
        });
        pDT = string.Format("{0:dd.MM}", dt.Rows[x]("EventDate"));
        titles = dt.Rows[x]("Title") + ",";
    } else {
        titles += dt.Rows[x]("Title") + ",";
    }
}
titles = Strings.Mid(titles, 1, Strings.Len(titles) - 1);
newDT.Rows.Add({
    pDT,
    string.Join("<br>", titles.Split(",").ToArray)
});
rptDate.DataSource = newDT;
rptDate.DataBind();
```

aspx :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDate">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">
                        <%# Container.DataItem("Date")%>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <%# Container.DataItem("Titles")%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

css :

```
.td1, .td2 {width:250px; border-bottom:solid 1px gray; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;}
.td1 {font-weight:bold;}
.td2 {font-style:italic;}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected :). I just need to figure out the adding to a repeater now.

Comment: Here is my repeater... https://jsfiddle.net/bkasxw9x/. I am using DIV to make it responsive. If you are able to help me that would be great. The current repeater just displays one date per section.

Comment: @Si8 I just update my answer. I use `table`, but You can change it to `tag` You need it. It's point about new `DataTable` (in codebehind) and `<%# Container.DataItem("Field_name")%>` in aspx, in `Repeater`.

Comment: Thanks. What is `Mid` supposed to do?

Comment: I think it's `Substring` ... it remove last `,` from `titles` to avoid extra `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void rptTeste_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepeater")).Text = ((DateTime)((dynamic)(e.Item.DataItem)).EventDate).ToString("MM/dd");
    }
```

Comment: Here is repeater: https://jsfiddle.net/bkasxw9x/. Can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

in .aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCalendar" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="rptCalendar_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="calEvParent widthFull hidOverflow" style="padding: 0 0 8px 0;">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="calEvHolder width98 hidOverflow" style="height: 55px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51); box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7); margin: 10px 0 0 1%;">
        <div class="calEvDateHolder floatL hidOverflow heightFull" style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="calEvDate widthFull heightFull hidOverflow dispIB textC">
                <span style="font-size: 32px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 300; font-family: 'Lato';"><%# Eval("EventDate", "{0:dd}") %></span>
                <br />
                <span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 800; font-family: 'Lato';">
                    <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EventDate")).ToString("MMM") %>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 72%; height: 100%; padding: 0 0 0 2%; overflow: hidden;">
        <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtList">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h2 style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 700; margin: 0px; font-family: 'Lato';"><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
                <span style="font-size: .6em;"><%# Eval("Location") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>             
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

And set repeater DataSource:

```
var groupedObjectList = from DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                                group r by r.Field<DateTime>("EventDate") into g
                                select new { EventDate = g.Key, Items = g.Select(i => new { Title = i.Field<string>("Title"), Location = i.Field<string>("Location") }).ToList() };

        rptCalendar.DataSource = groupedObjectList;
        rptCalendar.DataBind();
```

And rptCalendar_ItemDataBound Event:

```
protected void rptCalendar_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            DataList itemList = ((DataList)e.Item.FindControl("dtList"));
            itemList.DataSource = ((dynamic)(e.Item.DataItem)).Items;
            itemList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedObjectList = from DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                                  group r by r.Field<DateTime>("EventDate") into g
                                  select new { EventDate = g.Key, Items = g.ToList() };
```

Comment: If I have a repeater and I would like to use it for each `groupedObjectList`, how can I do that? It is a DataTable not a DataSet.

Comment: In ItemDataBound event of Repeater, you can get value Data like: ((dynamic)(e.Item.DataItem)).EventDate

Comment: And set text in child control like ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepeater")).text